# DrawerNavigator to show tab bar all the time with every option tapped

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to have a tab bar and each tab bar has its own stack navigator. Three tabs that i have are
Home
Profile
Settings

I want to show these three options in the drawer also. I have created a drawer but only tapping home shows the tab bar. I want to show tab bar just like if you press of profile tab and tab bar remains there.

[image: Tabs with their stack navigators]

[image: Side drawer with same options]

[image: Tapping profile from drawer hides tab bar]

Here is my code:

```js
const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
export const HomeNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <HomeStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavOptions}>
      <HomeStackNavigator.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={homeScreenOptions}
      />
       <HomeStackNavigator.Screen
        name="Details"
        component={DetailsScreen}
        options={detailsScreenOptions}
      />
    </HomeStackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};

const ProfileStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
export const ProfileNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <ProfileStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavOptions}>
      <ProfileStackNavigator.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={profileScreenOptions}
      />
       <ProfileStackNavigator.Screen
        name="EditProfile"
        component={EditProfileScreen}
        options={editProfileScreenOptions}
      />
    </ProfileStackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};

const SettingsStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
export const SettingsNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <SettingsStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavOptions}>
      <SettingsStackNavigator.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={settingsScreenOptions}
      />
       <SettingsStackNavigator.Screen
        name="AccountDetail"
        component={AccountDetailsScreen}
        options={accountDetailsScreenOptions}
      />
    </SettingsStackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};




const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();
export const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <HomeTabNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavOptions}>
      <HomeTabNavigator.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
       <HomeTabNavigator.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="face-profile" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <HomeTabNavigator.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-settings" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </HomeTabNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};



const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export const Drawer = () => {
  return(
      <AppDrawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <AppDrawer.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigator} />
        <AppDrawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileNavigator} />
        <AppDrawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsNavigator} />
      </AppDrawer.Navigator>
  )
};
```

My goal is to have tabs all the time. Tabs should hide only if we go to the detail page of any of the tabs.

Comment: Yes because you set tabbar only in home

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But setting 3 tab bars is not a solution. I think there should be some other approach to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your `TabNavigator` a screen of a stack navigator which is a screen of your drawer navigator and pass a custom drawer component to your drawer navigator:

```
const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <HomeTabNavigator.Navigator>
      <HomeTabNavigator.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        }}
      />
      <HomeTabNavigator.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
        }}
      />
      <HomeTabNavigator.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        }}
      />
    </HomeTabNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItem
        label="Home"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Profile"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Settings"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

function getHeaderTitle(route) {
  return getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Home';
}

const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Tabs"
        component={TabNavigator}
        options={({route}) => ({
          headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="EditProfile" component={EditProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AccountDetail" component={AccountDetailsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export const Drawer = () => {
  return (
    <AppDrawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <AppDrawer.Screen name="Stack" component={StackNavigator} />
    </AppDrawer.Navigator>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The screens you don't want to show the tabs for can be put inside the stack navigator outside of the tab navigator.

---

Sources:

- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent.
- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state.

*Be sure to import `DrawerItem`, `DrawerContentScrollView` from `@react-navigation/drawer` and `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute` from `@react-navigation/native.`*

Comment: But, this code doesn't synchron the Drawer and Bottom Tab, vise versa. When I access 'Profile' from Drawer, the Bottom Tab doesn't active the 'Profile', it always active the 'Home' tab, whenever I navigate other page from drawer.